# Deleting association record in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations, delete-record

I have two models.

```
class User<<ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :projects
end

class Project<<ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
end
```

Then in console, I load a project in variable 'p' and an user in variable 'u'.
Consider the following commands

```
u = User.first
p = Project.first
u.projects<<p
```

Now,

u.projects and p.user, both are showing correct amd expected output.

**My question is that how can I delete project 'p' from projects of user 'u' such that result is reflected in both the models.**

I have tried doing

```
u.projects.delete(p)
```

This only removes 'p' from projects of 'u'

but p.user still shows 'u' which I don't want. 
So, how I can I manage this?

Comment: your objects are still in memory, `u.reload` and `u.projects` should not show the removed project

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your answer actually solved most of my doubts regarding association. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a reload operation using `u.reload` solved my problems.
Thanks to `mr_sudaca` for suggesting. Reload operation fetches the latest state of records from db and refreshes the objects stored in memory to reflect latest state of objects.